# Passing query as string to elasticsearch using Mpdreamz/NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I started using NEST and got it working. I see that the query as string is depricated. Is there another way of doing this? lets say I want to search for "test" in the whole index.

Answer (score 0):

Passing as string is indeed deprecated but will not be removed.

To search for a term over all indices use:

```
this.ConnectedClient.Search<MyDTO>(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    .Query(q=>q.Term(f=>f.Name, ""))
);
```

Make sure to look at the test project and the documentation which have alot of example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the querystring query type if all you are looking for is to search by a single word across all fields for a document type.

```
Client.Search<T>(q=>q.Index("MyIndex").Query(q=>q.QueryString("test")))
```